# Best way to integrate ReactVR inside an existing React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-360

anyone can explain the best way to integrate a new ReactVR app inside an existing React app? I must iframe it or there is a way to integrate directly? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

React VR is more akin to React Native so its not really apples and apples. I believe the iFrame will be your best bet here. This is the recommended method according to the documentation.

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/publishing.html